# Android - Simplify ViewModel and Repository classes with OOP

Tags: java, object-oriented, android, mvvm

Let's say I have 2 repository classes:

```
public class XRepository {
    private XDao xDao;
    private LiveData<List<X>> allXs;

    public XRepository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        xDao = database.xDao();
        allXs = xDao.getAllXs();
    }
    public void insert(X x) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> xDao.insert(x));
    }
    public void update(X x) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> xDao.update(x));
    }
    public void delete(X x) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> xDao.delete(x));
    }
    public void deleteAll() {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> xDao.deleteAll());
    }
    public LiveData<List<X>> getAllXs() {
        return allXs;
    }
}

public class YRepository {
    private YDao yDao;
    private LiveData<List<Y>> allYs;

    public YRepository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        yDao = database.yDao();
        allYs = yDao.getAllYs();
    }
    public void insert(Y y) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> yDao.insert(y));
    }
    public void update(Y y) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> yDao.update(y));
    }
    public void delete(Y y) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> yDao.delete(y));
    }
    public void deleteAll() {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> yDao.deleteAll());
    }
    public LiveData<List<Y>> getAllYs() {
        return allYs;
    }
}
```

And most of my ViewModels have `insert`, `update`, `delete` methods which uses their corresponding repository instance.

```
public class XListingFragmentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private XRepository xRepository;
    private LiveData<List<X>> allXs;

    public XListingsFragmentViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        xRepository = new XRepository(application);
        allXs = xRepository.getAllXs();
    }
    public void insert(X x) { xRepository.insert(x); }
    public void update(X x) { xRepository.update(x); }
    public void delete(X x) { xRepository.delete(x); }
    public void deleteAll() { xRepository.deleteAll(); }
    public LiveData<List<X>> getAllXs() { return allXs; }

    .. Other fragment specific methods
}

public class AddEditXFragmentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private XRepository xRepository;

    public AddEditXFragmentViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        xRepository = new XRepository(application);
    }
    public void insert(X x) { xRepository.insert(x); }
    public void update(X x) { xRepository.update(x); }
    public void delete(X x) { xRepository.delete(x); }

    .. Other fragment specific methods
}

public class YListingFragmentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private YRepository yRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Y>> allYs;

    public XListingsFragmentViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        yRepository = new YRepository(application);
        allYs = yRepository.getAllYs();
    }
    public void insert(Y y) { yRepository.insert(y); }
    public void update(Y y) { yRepository.update(y); }
    public void delete(Y y) { yRepository.delete(y); }
    public void deleteAll() { yRepository.deleteAll(); }
    public LiveData<List<Y>> getAllYs() { return allYs; }

    .. Other fragment specific methods
}

public class AddEditYFragmentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private YRepository yRepository;

    public AddEditYFragmentViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        yRepository = new YRepository(application);
    }
    public void insert(Y y) { yRepository.insert(y); }
    public void update(Y y) { yRepository.update(y); }
    public void delete(Y y) { yRepository.delete(y); }

    .. Other fragment specific methods
}
```

They are very similar to each other and I think I am repeating a lot of codes. Any idea how I can simplify these using OOP? Or some sort of design pattern maybe?
P.S. I am using Room Persistence Library

Comment: Do you have code ownership to the `XDao` and `YDao` classes? If you do, then you can change them to implement a common generic `Dao<T>` interface and do away with a single parameterized `Repository<T>` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @TorbenPutkonen, if you have the ownership on your dao classes then you can parameterize them.

```
abstract class Repository<X> {
  private LiveData<List<X>> allEntities;
  private Dao<X> dao;

  void insert(X entity);

}

abstract class ListingFragmentViewModel<X> {
  private Repository<X> repository;
  public void insert(X entity) { 
    repository.insert(x); 
  }
}
```